# Browser installation on CentOS

Tags: linux, google-chrome, centos

after install the latest stable version of Google Chrome on a fresh CentOS 7 I get this error when trying to run it as "root".

```
[root@ip-172-31-49-161 /]# google-chrome &
[4] 11889
[root@ip-172-31-49-161 /]# [1:1:0912/031926:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(111)] Couldn't load libexif.
[1:1:0912/031926:ERROR:nacl_fork_delegate_linux.cc(314)] Bad NaCl helper startup ack (0 bytes)
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?